# Stopping a working thread while querying Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, multithreading, facebook-graph-api

**CONTEXT**

We have this activity method, called at `onCreate` starting a Thread :

```
public void retrieveInfoFromFB(){

     new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                getMyPersonalInfo();
                getMeEvents();

            }}).start();
}
```

`getMyPersonalInfo()` and `getMeEvents()` do a Request to Facebook both like that:

```
      if (session!=null && session.isOpened()){

          Request request=new Request(session,"/fql",params, HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {

            public void onCompleted(Response response){

               // do something with response

                }
            });

    Request.executeAndWait(request);    
     }
```

**PROBLEM**

When the connection is low *(not absent, just very low)* we have this Thread "working"  forever without stopping after a while, yes we already tried to use a RequestBatch with [setTimeout(milliseconds)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/RequestBatch/) for the Requests, but this seemed not to work.

**QUESTION**

*Is there a way to stop the "retrieveInfoFromFB" thread after (let's say) 10 seconds, while is still waiting for the response from Facebook requests?*

**p.s**
I searched in stackoverflow questions, it seems that all the methods like `myThread.destroy()` or `myThread().interrupt()`, are deprecated. And we can't use a `while` with a flag to do these two request because they must be done just once.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to stop the thread communicating with FB (unless you stop the process). However, you can ask the thread to stop itself.

For that you need the FB thread to periodically check if any other process or thread asked it to stop working.

Check out this tutorial on threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html, but basically you want this:

```
// communicating with FB
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000); sleep one second to give other threads a chance
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // We've been interrupted: stop talking to FB and return
    return;
}
```

or

```
// do some more FB work
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    // We've been interrupted: no more FB
    return;
}
```

On either case it is the FB thread that must periodically check if it is time to stop, as it is its job to do any cleanup that might be required.

Comment: Ok so, if I'm not wrong, these two Request are called with executeAndWait() so they are run in the retrieveInfoFromFb thread. Basically what I have to do is to support interruption in this thread? Stopping it from the main thread. Is it right?

Comment: @user3383667, If this is the right answer, could you please mark it as such?

Comment: hehe two years spent to review this answer, finally I decided to mark it as the correct one.